# pyinstaller syntax error itertools and groupby

Tags: python, python-3.4, pyinstaller, python-itertools

Im receiving the following syntax errorwhile trying to compile my script

```
    forst, *mid, sist = times
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The code that i believe is causing it is the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
dates = [datetime.strptime(item, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M') for item in listan]
from itertools import groupby
for day, times in groupby(dates, lambda x: x.date()):
    forst, *mid, sist = times
    listanklar = (forst, sist)
    for item in listanklar:
        file2.write (str("%s\n" % item))
```

The code runs perfectly but i cant compile it.
I am using Python 3.4
Is this a problem with pyinstaller?
what can i do to sort this out.